How to make sure token always fresh in google new credential manager for Android
is there a property, class, function of Google Credential Manager for android that make sure ID Token always fresh when making API call to backend. this API call will return Bearer Token to authenticate with my API.
maybe similar to this firebase function to force token refresh:
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.getIdToken(true)

I Expect A way to get ID token without making user logged in again
